# sed unterminated 's' command

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the below sed command:

```
Ctimezone="$shortName = exec('date +%Z');\
  $longName = timezone_name_from_abbr($shortName);\
  date_default_timezone_set($longName);"

sed -i 10s@.*@$Ctimezone@ /home/file.php
```

However this gives me the error:

```
sed -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated 's' command
```

My understanding of sed is not great so im sure its an easy fix but couldn't work it out myself.

If you need any more info let me know

Changed to:

```
sed -i "10s@.*@$Ctimezone@" /home/file.php
```

but what is put into file.php is:

> = exec('date +%Z'); = timezone_name_from_abbr(); date_default_timezone_set();

not

> $shortName = exec('date +%Z'); $longName = timezone_name_from_abbr($shortName); date_default_timezone_set($longName);

Comment: You need to quote the sed expression: `sed -i "10s@.*@$Ctimezone@" /home/file.php`

Comment: I'm not sure what the @ symbol does to bash variables, but try changing the $Ctimezone to ${Ctimezone} in the actual sed command.

Comment: @fedorqui that works however what ends up being entered into the file.php is " = exec('date +%Z'); = timezone_name_from_abbr(); date_default_timezone_set();

Comment: yes, that's what your code does. we have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry everything thing within the Ctimezone should be a treated as a string so $shortName is not a bash variable etc.

Comment: Zac, you should enclose the RHS of `Ctimezone` in single quotes then so that shell doesn't expand the `$` terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables get expanded in double quotes, and since `$shortName` isn't set, it becomes an empty string.

Escape the dollar signs: `\$`.

Or, if the file you're trying to modify allows `exec("date +%Z");` try to switch `'` and `"`. There's no substitution within single quotes.